# Create apk file on run time by filling html page fields

Tags: java, android, servlets, android-sdk-2.3

I want to create an apk file on runtime using the details that user filled in a html page like application name ,application background icon and other drawables. The user just need to fill all the details and click on a create button will generate the apk file having all the data that i have filled.

I have an idea to keep the Android SDK on server and compile the code on backend and when it finished we give an option of downloading application on the page.

But no idea how to implement it please help me.

they are doing the same http://www.appsgeyser.com/create/start/ check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Infrastructure**

1. VPS or a cloud hosting server. There are several providers such as Go Daddy and Rackspace. Do your research and find the best one that suits your needs.
2. Install Java, Android SDK and your application server on your VPS / Cloud server.

**Code**

1. You need to have a template of the Android project that you are going to build.
2. Create a custom source code based on user specific information.
3. Run aN Ant build script to generate the APK, you will also need to sign it with a key that is valid for 50 years. This can be configured in the Ant task itself.
4. Copy the APK to your public HTML folder and display the link to the user.

**Running the Ant Build Programmatically**
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_gawor/0502_gawor.html

[Running ANT Programmatically Through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035188/running-ant-programmatically-through-java)

**Update**

Use Gradle, it's a lot more easier.

Comment: i have no idea abour running the ant build script could you please be more descriptive ?

Comment: please provide any sample if available on github so anywhere else