# Can you run Ant on a buildfile that is located inside a jar?

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

I am wondering if you can run Ant on a buildfile that would be located inside a JAR.  The reason why I am interested in this is because I would like to include a "deploy" target in my buildfile that could be called after the jar has been moved to its destination.  That "deploy" target would take care of extracting resources and other libraries required to run the program.

So, for instance, I would package up properties, images and external jars inside of my jar when building.  The deployment process would then consist of moving the jar to the location it is meant to run in, and call `ant <someOption> myjar.jar/build.xml deploy` or something like that.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515394/running-an-ant-build-xml-file-inside-a-jar-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there isn't a way `ant` can get a build file inside a jar.

For the method you described, you'll need to unzip `build.xml` and pass it to ant. Since ant does not take `stdin` as an argument to the buildfile, you'll need to store the buildfile then delete it:

`$ unzip myjar.jar build.xml`

`$ ant deploy`

`$ rm build.xml`

But is it necessary to the application running environment have ant installed only to extract these resources? Couldn't it be done inside your application? Or can't you distribute a zip file with you jar, library jars and images?

Or maybe creating an installer should be more appropriate: [I\Pack](http://izpack.org/) or, if Windows only, [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you. If the target environment is going to run java code, and the build process already leverages ant, I thought it might as well become the installer.  But it looks like more complexity than necessary.  I think I will compile and build the jar, build the directory structure and then zip the whole thing up.  Then I can just unzip on the target machine.

Answer (score 1):

Ant's build file parsing can be extended using [ProjectHelper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/projecthelper.html).  Default one loads only files ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.ant/com.springsource.org.apache.tools.ant/1.7.1/org/apache/tools/ant/ProjectHelper.java#ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper%28%29)).

You could extend it to process an XML source, which can come from a jar (probably using getResourceAsStream(..))

[ Side note: You can run ant programmatically. No need to extract and then run command line - see [Running ANT Programmatically Through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035188/running-ant-programmatically-through-java) ]