# How to get status of build with Ant using ProcessBuilder (Java)

Tags: java, ant

I'm using the following code:

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add(antExecutable);
command.add("test");

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
processBuilder.directory(new File("C:\\Testing\\projects...myPath..."));

Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

And the question is: How can i get the build-status? Is it failed or not..?

Answer (score 0):

Your only choice in this case to depend on exit code. By convention, it must be 0 for success and non zero for failures.

Having said that, your case could be improved by running ant directly in your Java application. See a discussion in SO question [Running ANT Programmatically Through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035188/running-ant-programmatically-through-java,or) from a quick [google search result](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=run%20ant%20programmatically&oq=run%20ant%20programmatically) such as  [IBM Developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_gawor/0502_gawor.html)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll try to make use of this approach.